# Display all results of SQL query (including where count 0)

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have the following Query:

```
SELECT airportname, COUNT(DISTINCT foundBag.id) countFound, COUNT(DISTINCT lostBag.id) countLost 
FROM airports 
INNER JOIN foundBag ON airport_id = foundBag.airportDest 
INNER JOIN lostBag ON airport_id = lostBag.airportDest 
GROUP BY airport.airportname");
```

What I have now: A table that has 3 columns: Airport name with the number of bags found and number of bags lost.
It only displays an airport (row) when both of the columns are filled.

I want 2 things:

1. To display all the airports even when there are no lost / found bags.
2. To display the airports where the are lost / found bags (so when 1 or both the columns are filled)

I tried this with When etc. but it keeps giving me errors. I also tried the EXISTS but I'm new to SQL so I do not know how it works...

Does someone have a solution?

Kind regards,

LTKort

Comment: mysql <> sql server. Please don't tag products not involved

Comment: show data sample and expected result

Comment: Search `inner join vs left join`

Comment: Agree with @HoneyBadger. You need to use `Left Join` instead.

Comment: Also, your `Group By` statement will produce errors. `GROUP BY airport.airportname");` The table name is `airports` and the double quotes `"` and parenthesis doesn't look right either.

Comment: Thanks @HoneyBadger Left join works! Is there a possibility to only show airports where one (lost or found) is empty? Instead of all airports?

Comment: you want to add where count(xxx) is null

Comment: @LTKort don't you mean where a record for `lost` or a record for `found` exists? See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for both conditions:

```
SELECT airportname, COUNT(DISTINCT foundBag.id) countFound, COUNT(DISTINCT lostBag.id) countLost 
FROM airports 
LEFT JOIN foundBag ON airport_id = foundBag.airportDest 
LEFT JOIN lostBag ON airport_id = lostBag.airportDest 
WHERE foundBag.airportDest is not null
   or lostBag.airportDest is not null
GROUP BY airport.airportname
```